# How to do foreach in JS using data from laravel views?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, leaflet, gis

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-6.935118, 107.766995], 15);

 L.marker([-6.93155, 107.775831]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('Bus Stops')
  .openPopup();
```

I have this function on javascript, and I have a database that store the lat, lng, and the place name. Is there any possible way that I can do a loop so the marker is added automatically from what I have in my database? I'm using laravel blade. PS: its a leafletjs

Comment: you can get the define a js variable to hold that data https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json

Comment: @ChinhNguyen if I make a js array, then how do I assign the lat, lng, name to the required parameter?

Comment: just loop and call the js function yourself in js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, modify your JS function to something similar to this:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, place){
         L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map)
         .bindPopup(place)
         .openPopup();
        }
```

For old versions of laravel:

```
<script>
    var coordinates = <?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>;
</script>
```

For latest versions of laravel:

```
<script>
    var coordinates = {{ Js::from($coordinates) }};
</script>
```

Then Loop through the array :

```
<script>
    coordinates.foreEach(function(item){
        addMarker(item.lat, item.lng, item.place);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is easy to understand and worked for me, thank you. the {{ Js::from($coordinates) }}; worked but some reason vscode detected it as error "property assignment expected, identifier expected, declaration or statement expected."

Answer (score 1):

you must get the all data and make it into Api
i make my Javascript like this

```
async function getAllMarker() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    const res = await fetch("/api");
    const data = await res.json();
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const position = {
            lat: Number(item.latitude),
            lng: Number(item.longitude),
        };
        addMarker(position, map, item);
    });
}
```

for Add Marker my Function Look Like This

```
function addMarker(position, map, item){
         L.marker(position).addTo(map)
         .bindPopup(item.marker)
         .openPopup();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure about that but you could try doing something like that

```js
// We will loop for every element/index inside the L if it's an array it should
// work,   here we declare l variable so we can use inside the foreach loop
L.forEach((l) => {
  // Example
  console.log(l);
});
```

As well i can't test it because i don't have the code, It would be great if you added the variable `L` to the code so i can help you more with it.

If the `L` is convertible to `Array` or it's already an array it should work.
For more information about forEach loops check [here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If `L` is not an array you might need to add `L.toArray().forEach`,
You can follow this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_string_toarray.htm) to see prototypes for toArray() method.